# Uploading to Cloudinary from App Engine is slow

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, cloudinary

I am uploading images to Cloudinary from my Node.js App Engine server using the `cloudinary` SDK. Images are taking too long to upload. Some observations made:

```
size    time

 31Kb     750ms
536Kb   36114ms
5.5Mb   59619ms
```

Back when the server was hosted on Heroku, images uploads were way faster (never more than 2000 ms). Is external network egress from App Engine outside of Google to blame here? How can I get parity with Heroku?

Also, if I run my server locally and upload to Cloudinary, uploads are pretty fast. Why does App Engine make uploads slow?

Comment: External Network Egress could be the cause indeed, however it probably also relates to a big distance between the App Engine server and the Cloudinary location, this could also explain why your local upload is faster, have you checked if the locations that you are using in Cloudnary and your App Engine server are the closest possible locations?

Comment: @ralemos not sure where Cloudinary is hosted but our App Engine app is hosted in `us-central`

Comment: Try changing your app engine regions and check if there is any improvement.